# Is it possible to pass data to a controller from RouteConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a custom CMS, and I'm making it from scratch.

I have created a custom route handler to pass dynamic Url's to the correct controller. This unfortunately requires that I look up the url in the database to find the corresponding controller.

I would like to pass the object I receive from the db to the controller is this possible? The reason is to prevent a second trip to the db when I get to the controller as I intend to use the same object there.

If it matters I am using MVC 5 and Dynamo DB.

TL;DR; Is it possible to pass an object to a controller from RouteConfig.

EDIT: For clarity I am adding the code from the route and handler though I can not see why it matters.

The route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{*UrlName}").RouteHandler = new UrlNameRouteHandler();
```

The custom handler:

```
public class UrlNameRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var urlName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["UrlName"] != null ? requestContext.RouteData.Values["UrlName"].ToString() : "Start";
        var page = PageManager.GetPageByUrlName(urlName);
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = page.ControllerName;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "index";

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Using a cache would of course work to get data into the controller, and I do have a working solution using a cache, but that is not why I posed the question. I want to know if I can *directly* send data to a controller from a route handler.

Comment: Can we see your custom route handler? and an example of the DB model that you are trying to pass into the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to pass the object I receive from the db to the
>   controller is this possible?

RouteConfig will be fired from Application_Start() event of Global.asax, so it will be executed for only one time. Ideally this workflow will limit number of options for you to pass data from RouteConfig to controllers.

I would suggest, you to put the object in routeconfig in [Cache object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and then use it in controllers. So you put your object in Cache and from there onwards, use the object from Cache.

**EDIT**

As per your question's updated information, you can use RouteData or HttpContext.Items[] collection to pass data to controller.

Comment: Using a cache does solve the issue with getting the data into the controller, but unfortunately this is not what I asked :) I just want to know if it is possible to send data _directly_ to the controller at all?

Comment: @Oddxen Directly from where? If it is from HttpModule or ActionFilter or Application AcquireRequestState, then definitely YES, because they get executed on every request. And you can use RouteData or HttpContext.Items[] collection to pass data to controller.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I had a real doh' moment when I see in my code that I use HttpContext.Current.Cache, and didn't find it [HttpContext.Current.Items[]] when googeling for more functionality. Marking your answer as correct. Maybe update your response for the googelers.

Comment: Forgot to say thank you. I had been struggling with the issue for a while now so you just made my day!

Comment: @Oddxen, Not a problem at all, I am happy that I can help you out.